# Como somar valores em javascripte pelo innerHTM

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu fiz um teclado com valores grandes, onde ao apertar o botão, a intenção é ir somando os números descritos: os campos estão assim chamando a função:

```
<button class="botao" onclick="insert ('1000')">+1000</button>
```

e sendo recebidos dessa forma:

```
<script>
function insert (num){
 numero = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = numero + num;

}
function clean(){
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";

}
```

ocorre que ele está concatenando invés de somar, ao tentar transformar com parseInt() dessa forma:

```
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = parseInt(numero) + parseInt(num);
```

também não funciona pois retorna NaN, o que devo fazer?

Answer (score -2):

Na função use assim:  `= parseFloat(numero) + parseFloat(num);`

Se forem números inteiros: `= parseInt(numero) +parseInt(num);`

Comment: eu fiz exatamente dessa forma e ele retorna NaN

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

O problema que você encontrou é devido a forma que você está passando o parâmetro da sua função, você esta passando uma string, logo ele irá contatenar, você deve passar o valor inteiro, ao invés de mandar:

```
onclick="insert ('1000')"
```

você deve passar:

```
onclick="insert (1000)"
```

Como o valor inicial da sua função é vazio também defina um valor inicial como 0 caso esteja vazio, pois senão realmente retornará um erro.

**seu código ficará mais ou menos assim:**

```js
function insert (num){
   var numero =document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML
   if(numero === ""){
    numero = 0;
   }
   var valor = parseInt(numero)+num
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = valor
}
function clean(){
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<button class="botao" onclick="insert(1000)">+1000</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
<button class="botao" onclick="clean()">clear</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

tente iniciar a DIV resultado com valor = 0;
e na função clean também coloque 0: document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "0";